# How can I duplicate an image li item within a ul to a second ul on "action"?

Tags: html, duplicates

I'm working on a project which contains a list of images in an unordered list and I thought it would be neat to be able to perform an action which would duplicate the list item and add it to a second unordered list. Essentially this would be creating a list of favorites while maintaining the original list.

I'm fairly new to html so I'm not sure how I could go about achieving this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty easy with [`JOuery`](http://jquery.com/).

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm just learning JQuery as well. Would you be able to give an example? I've been trying something like this:

`if (e.ctrlKey){
$('.menu').attr('id', selectId);
selectId.clone(true).appendTo('.favMenu ul');
}`

Comment: If you want to trigger your action by clicking on one of the images, you need to add Event Listeners to all your original images.

Comment: @PM77-1 I've figured it out, thanks. Do you know how I can avoid a list item from being duplicated a second time? For example, if an image is clicked it is added to the favorite menu. How can I avoid it being able to be added multiple times?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the entire [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/25brL/2/) (without actual images) in pure JS.

I implemented exclusion of duplicates through the `for` loop inside the following function:

```
function copyToFavorites(event) {
    var image = event.srcElement;
    var src = image.src;
    var dup;

    // determine if it's a duplicate
    var ul = document.getElementById("fav");
    var images = ul.getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) { 
        dup = (images[i].src === src);
        if (dup) {
            break;
        }    
    }
    // if not a duplicate - add to favorites
    if (! dup) {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var newImg = document.createElement("img");
        newImg.src = src;
        li.appendChild(newImg);
        ul.appendChild(li);
    } else {
        alert("This ismage is already in Favorites");
    }
}
```

Could not come up with anything more elegant.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I came up with some similar eventually. Here it is:


`$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.menu').find('a').click(function(e){
  var selectName = $(this).attr('name'),
   selectId = $(this).attr('id');
  if (e.which == 2){
  $(".favMenu").append('<li>' + $(this).html() + '</li>');
    
  } 
 });
});`

You're code definitely does more than mine as the duplication issue was one I hadn't solved.

However, I found I was not able to edit the css for those duplicated elements so that they had a green border, for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using javascript, jQuery or any other help. Check this example using jQuery. It only have text in the example but it will work perfect with any content inside the li tag. http://goo.gl/bplTrm